# WPF Datagrid Syling

Tags: wpf, datagrid

[image]

Please let me know how can I remove vertical grid line for last column only.

Thanks
Dee

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming AutoGenerateColumn=True. If so, use the AutoGeneratingColumn event which is called when the column is generated, which means the attribute to add in xaml would be
AutoGeneratingColumn=DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn

And the handler code will be something like this

```
private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e) 
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "+") //or whatever it is
            {
                e.Cancel = false;
                e.Column.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
    }
```

**Update based on comment**

This is just a simple example. Try setting cell style like so

In xaml add

```
<Style x:Key="noborder" TargetType="{x:Type dg:DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
</Style>
```

In the event handler add

```
e.Column.CellStyle = this.Resources["noborder"] as Style;
```

You can play with different style properties to get it right

Comment: Actually I have AutoGenerateColumn = false. That extra column which I have added. I tried to give same visibility.collapsed to last column and it hides whole column. I still want to have + button to add column.

Comment: I would try setting cellstyle then. Will update answer with details.

Comment: I tried this but it's not line for cell or any column. It's datagrid vertical line. I can only see one option to make it hide is set column with 100%.

Answer (score 0):

mark the last column width with a star

```
<DataGridTextColumn .... Width="*"
```

that way your current last column (filler) won't appear, rather your real last column that you declared in your XAML file will stretch to the end of the visible area in the grid.